# 'Is Fuutarou's theme supposed to be like Survivor's Eye of the Tiger?' - Please explain the lock

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Is Fuutarou's theme supposed to be like Survivor's Eye of the Tiger?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66643/is-fuutarous-theme-supposed-to-be-like-survivors-eye-of-the-tiger)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I mistakenly locked this question as part of ongoing depreciation of music id-request. Regardless it should have been closed as opinionated.

This straddles the link in acceptable opinionated questions related to music. You have a 3 second clip with a riff that you presume sample the "Eye of the Tiger" song. The clip sample size provides hardly any evidence to justify that it was sampled, inspired or otherwise copied from the alleged original song. While it's true that there are music thare draw inspiration from other works for effect (as in not a near exact copy of the riff), the evidence you provide does not make this connection or does it explain why you believe it to be so. So in lack of any clear evidence to support your case, the question is based on your subjected assumptions rather than evidently explained facts.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. Re 'The clip sample size provides hardly any evidence to justify that it was sampled, inspired or otherwise copied from the alleged original song' --> Well if there was some Japanese article out there then probably. I read some comments that say 'it is the same chord progression.' I'll edit post.

Comment: While true, good chord combinations/archetypes are limited so there will be instances where one piece has a similar progression as another. Anything beyond that fact requires a longer sample for comparison.

Comment: кяαzєя Cool. Thanks. We're so lucky to have a mod who knows music and stuff here. So how many seconds for the sample?

Comment: It depends. It's like comparing vocal patterns to see if people sound alike. Sometimes it's simple when you have same phrase, but can be difficult with different phrases/pitches/tones.

Comment: There are no lyrics here...soooo...?

Comment: Overall it's not a good question to ask if you cannot establish that your point is not just something in your head (i.e., your own opinion). It could be intentional but it could be coincidental. The burden of proof is for you to establish the connection with a convincing argument and not something like because I think so. I've listed scenarios and examples in the comment of your question for context.

Comment: кяαzєя seems like a little catch-22. If I come up with some connection, then it's like the answer already. What if there's some Japanese article out there on this which I simply can't find because my google search is in English?

Comment: It's not. The site prefers facts over speculation. If you have a hypothesis you want to ask about. Present your thesis and explain why you think so instead of claiming it is so because you think it is so. Personal bias makes for bad, subjective questions. Furthermore you cannot assume something exists before you find it. Japanese articles aren't all knowing or all encompassing (the internals of anime and manga production is still a niche topic, despite it's popularity of it's metaculture). Unless it comes from an author's give source close to the production it's just hearsay.